# How can I auto focus on a textfield using Win32 GUI in Perl?

Tags: perl, user-interface, textfield, autofocus

I'm following an online [Win32::Gui tutorial](http://dada.perl.it/gui_docs/guiconcepts.html) to learn how to add a GUI to my Perl application. So far everything's been good. But I'm having some pesky small problems. So I'm asking for help here again.

One problem is, I have to click my mouse in the textfield before I can type. I tried something lie this:

```
$Object->AddTextfield(
        -name   => "Birthday",
        -left   => 75,
        -top    => 50,
        -width  => 180,
        -height => 20,
        -number => 1,
        -prompt => "Input birthday:",       

    );


$Object->Birthday->GetFocus();
$Object->Birthday->Activate();
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone kindly help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about `$Object->Birthday->`[`SetFocus()`](http://perl-win32-gui.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/docs.cgi?doc=reference-methods#setfocus)?

Comment: @ax, Thanks. But test failed.

Comment: @ax, I dunno what just happened. But now setfocus() is working :) Haha, thanks a lot dude !

Answer (score -1):

Birthday->SetFocus() will work fine....

you can try

Comment: Yes, @Rahul. SetFocus() does work. That's why I accepted the solution offered by @ax. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please do not just repeat other answers.